# unix time - calculating current hour in Java

Tags: java, date, unix, datetime

I am trying to get the current hour out of `System.currentTimeMillis()` but i can't seem to figure out how, I tried dividing the time in millisecs by 1000 which I suppose gives me seconds but I want to get the value of current hour. I guess if I do this time(ms)/1000 and then the resultant/3600 ? is it ?
Please advice.

Comment: why can't you create a `Calendar` object and get the `hour` from that?

Comment: CurrentTimeMillis contains a year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds etc. So if you want to get it through division, then keep this in mind.

Comment: actually i have a cassandra nodes at different location with different timezone than my local, from my local i am sending traffic with data containing current hour in a query for some operations, so i want the time in millisecs to be sure i don't key in the data with my local current time as when retrieving the data i would ask the server to send me back the data from current hour... or am i misinterpreting it ?

Comment: if i send the query with data having time in millisecs i suppose it would automatically be converted to the time at server and when retrieving the data i would ask the server again with current hour in millisecs and it would return me the data .. sometime like this i am trying to achive

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String time = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .getHour();
```

## java.time

Question and other Answers use troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by java.time.

Get current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone. For any given moment the date and the time-of-day vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.at( z );
```

Interrogate for hour-of-day.

```
int hourOfDay = zdt.getHour();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

## Count-from-epoch

In comments you mention wanting to track time as a count of milliseconds from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

I strongly recommend against this for multiple reasons. It makes debugging very difficult because a human cannot read a long integer and decipher a date-time meaning. So bugs may go undetected. A count-from-epoch is not self-documenting and the recipient may be confused as to its meaning. Some people count whole seconds from epoch, others milliseconds, others microseconds, others nanoseconds, and still others use other granularities. And as for epoch, which one? There are a [couple dozen different points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) in time used as an epoch reference in various computing systems.

But if you insist on using a count of milliseconds since the epoch of start of 1970 in UTC ( `1970-01-01T00:00:00` ), generate this number from an `Instant`.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpochOf1970 = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Instead, I suggest… When exchanging date-time values as strings, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These formats are human-readable, intuitive even across various cultures, self-documenting, recognizable, easy-to-parse, and sensible.

Generally you should be working in UTC. The ISO 8601 format for UTC values canonically uses a `Z` at the end, short for `Zulu`, and means UTC.

> 2016-09-16T20:46:01Z

This format is used by default when parsing/generating strings in the `Instant` class.

```
Instant.parse( "2016-09-16T20:46:01Z" )
myInstant.toString()  // Result: 2016-09-16T20:46:01Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
int hourOfDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to go the straight mathematics route, you'll want to use division and modulus.

```
long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Seconds " + x/1000);
x /= 1000;
System.out.println("Minutes " + x/60);
x /= 60;
System.out.println("Hours " + x/60);
x /= 60;
System.out.println("Hours (24hr) UTC - " + x%24);
System.out.println("Hours (12hr) UTC - " + x%12);
```

This will produce the following output (at this time, it was 7:50 pm UTC)

```
Seconds 1425930629
Minutes 23765510
Hours 396091
Hours (24hr) UTC - 19
Hours (12hr) UTC - 7
```

Comment: Well i guess this is what i was looking for, so i was right that first to divide with 1000 to get secs and then with 3600 to get hours, like in your example you first converted secs to minutes and then mins to hours.